# How does metallicity reduce the likelihood of black hole formation?

Tags: black-hole, supernova, metallicity

Large stars collapse and if they are large enough form black holes. But the likelihood reduces with metallicity.

[image]

What mechanism facilitates this? I believe it has something to do with opacity and Eddiington luminosity but haven't been able to find a source that pulls the information together in a conceptual manner.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for that image. It looks similar to https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Supernovae_as_initial_mass-metallicity.svg

Comment: Related question (with the same diagram): https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12707/16685 but the answers there don't give any details on the role of metallicity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metals have many electrons and many energy transitions available, therefore they are more likely to interact with photons (they increase the opacity). As a consequence, a star with higher metallicity will experience stronger winds, driven by the metal lines, that lead to a higher mass loss rate.

[image: the mass of a star as a function of time]
This plot from [Mapelli (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09130) shows the mass of a $90 M_\odot$ star as a function of time, for different metallicities. The higher $Z$, the more dramatic is mass loss.

This of course influences the mass of the black holes that can be produced. If at the end of its life, a star has retained only a small fraction of its initial mass, it will form a black hole much smaller than if it had not lost mass. And if the mass loss has been so dramatic that the mass of the compact remnant is below the [Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit), the result might be a neutron star instead of a black hole.

This is the main reason why the likelihood of forming a black hole decreases with metallicity. High metallicity stars can loose enough mass during their life, that they are more likely to form a neutron star.

Useful reference: [Heger et al. (2003)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/375341)

Comment: So just to make this 100% clear in my mind. A stars matter is like a sail to the photons, metallicity is like plugging any potential holes in that sail to increase it's capture of the wind?

Comment: @TheJeran Yes, it is a good analogy